# aws api gateway lambda proxy integration response error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

im trying to use AWS api gateway proxy integration with lambda to make an external api call, and i want to return the response as is back to the api gateway .

when i am executing my lambda with custom event every thing works fine , but when im trying to test it with api gateway i get an error.

**event example:**

```
{
  "requestType": "somedata",
  "requestID": "somedata",
  "createMagicLink": {
    "id": "somedata",
    "phone": "somedata",
    "urlID": "somedata",
    "callID": "somedata",
    "caller": "somedata",
    "toSendSMS": somedata
  }
}
```

**lambda example :**

```
import requests
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    url = "https://someUrl"
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json","API-TOKEN": "someToken", "content-type":"application/json"}
    data = event

                
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    json_response = response.json()
    json_obj = json_response['response']

    return {
        "isBase64Encoded": 'false',
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json_obj
        }
```

**lambda response , works fine :**

```
{
  "isBase64Encoded": "false",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "status": "0",
    "GUID": "******",
    "magicURL": "someUrl",
    "errorMessage": ""
  }
}
```

**when im trying to execute through api gateway post request im getting an internal server error 502 (ive changed the data var in my lambda function to data = event['body'] to catch the event from api gateway)**

```
Sat Feb 25 14:40:58 UTC 2023 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "'response'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/index.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    json_obj = json_response['response']\n"]}
Sat Feb 25 14:40:58 UTC 2023 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 'response'. Lambda request id: *
Sat Feb 25 14:40:58 UTC 2023 : Method completed with status: 502
```

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding `json.loads(event['body'])` and `json.dumps(json_obj)` to the lambda function

```
import requests
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    url = "https://someUrl"
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json","API-TOKEN": "someToken", "content-type":"application/json"}
    data = json.loads(event['body'])

                
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    json_response = response.json()
    json_obj = json_response['response']

    return {
        "isBase64Encoded": 'false',
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(json_obj)
    }
```

I hope it will help someone